# How can I report a bug in ConText?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I searched on [wiki.contextgarden.net](http://wiki.contextgarden.net) and [www.pragma-ade.com](http://www.pragma-ade.com/), but could not find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Create a minimal example

The minimal example should depict the problem as concise as possible. Remove
everything not directly related to the problem. Avoid the use of external
resources. If you need sample text, use [the files included in the
distribution](https://github.com/mojca/context-gitorious/tree/origin/tex/context/sample), e.g.

```
\input knuth
\input zapf
```

If you need images, use [the images shipped with the distribution](https://github.com/mojca/context-gitorious/tree/origin/tex/context/sample), e.g.

```
\setupexternalfigures [location=default]
…
\externalfigure [cow]
```

#### Make sure it hasn't been fixed already

Ensure the bug is not present in the latest version. Run your
minimal example on the latest beta, e.g. from [ConTeXt
standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone).

#### Approach the mailing list

The mailing list for reporting bugs is
[ntg-context](http://www.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context).
Please include your context version (the output of `context
--version`) and a short description of the bug (what did you expect
and what did you get instead).

Usually it's not necessary to include screenshots or other
attachments. More information about the mailing list can be found
[on the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Mailing_Lists).

#### Bug tracker

Bug tracking for ConTeXt is provided as part of the [LuaTeX project](http://tracker.luatex.org/my_view_page.php).

#### Backend bugs

If you assume you have found a bug in the LuaTeX backend, approach
the [LuaTeX mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/luatex)
and/or create a ticket on the [LuaTeX bug tracker](http://tracker.luatex.org/my_view_page.php).