# bug? unwanted gap in 2nd columnset

Tags: context, two-column, line-spacing, context-mkii

(Disclosure: I [posted](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2013/074972.html) this question on the NTG ConTeXt mailing list before the weekend. I have not received any replies yet, so now I'm asking here.)

We have a document where a gap occurs in a columnset under certain conditions.
It seems to be a confluence of:

- 2 sections, each with 2-column columnsets
- The first section ends in the first column of an even page, or the second column of an odd page.
- the 2nd section has a tighter interline space (which we normally accompany with a smaller font setting, but that's not required to exercise the bug)

The symptom of the problem is that on the first page of the second section, a gap appears (where gridlines 50 and 51 are, if you turn on `\showgrid`).

Screenshot of the problem:
[image: Gap across first page of second section]

It may be a coincidence, but 50 is also the number of lines per page in
the first section. We've found that "coincidence" to be true even with
different page and font sizes.

Can anyone tell us a way to get rid of the gap? We've tried things like

```
\setupcolumnsetlines[columnsetbibliography][4][1][-1]
\setupcolumnsetlines[columnsetbibliography][5][2][-1]
```

with various values for the last parameter, but nothing helps.

Below is a small, self-contained sample. We're using mkii, but a similar gap appears when we use mkiv.

Version information:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012)
(format=cont-en 2012.11.14)  13 SEP 2013 11:38
ConTeXt  ver: 2012.05.30 11:26 MKII  fmt: 2012.11.14  int: english/english
```

The example document:

```
\setupinterlinespace[line=12pt]

\definecolumnset[columnset1][n=2]
\setupcolumnset[columnset1][distance=5mm,balance=yes]

\starttext

\section{Introduction}
\startcolumnset[columnset1]
    \dorecurse {7} { \input knuth } 
\stopcolumnset

\section{Bibliography}
\setupinterlinespace[line=9.3pt]
\startcolumnset[columnset1]
    \dorecurse {10} { \input knuth }
\stopcolumnset

\stoptext
```

Many thanks... We are nearing the finish line on this long project, but have not been able to find a workaround for this problem.

Comment: Can you post a MWE (Minimal Working Example)? i.e. with preamble such that we could just copy/paste the code into our editors.

Comment: I can neither reproduce your problem with a current MkIV/MkII, nor with an old version from 2011.05.18.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, mea culpa. I just read 'context'...

Comment: @remus: No problem. I often miss tags too.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks for checking it out. Maybe that means there's a bug that's been fixed. What version number did you use for mkii? Was it from TeXlive 2013 or another installation? What OS? I'm using Windows and two Linux boxes, which give different results but all show the gap. Very strange that your 2011 version doesn't reproduce the problem; our version from 2005 does. I guess I'll try updating one of our systems to the 2013 version of TeX Live, but if your 2011 version couldn't repro the problem, that may not help.

Comment: It might have been fixed in the mean time. I tested with 2013.09.14 14:39 and 2011.05.18. The OS should not make any difference (I use Linux).

Comment: @Marco on my machine the same gap occurs both with the beta and TL 2013 (MkII and MkIV).

Comment: @LarsH the issue appears to be independent of the grid since it occurs with ``\setuplayout [grid=no]``. If you want lines to adhere to a tighter line spacing you will have to set a smaller font size, (the default one is 12pt I think) e.g. ``\setupbodyfont [7pt]`` gets you the desired baseline skip and decent leading. Doesn’t make the gap disappear, though.

Comment: Indeed. I can confirm the gap is present in a current beta. It's just on one single page, I missed it while scrolling.

Comment: @phg: Thanks for the repo report: I'm glad we're not alone. Thanks also regarding the font size. (Our real document does set the font size, and has the tighter line spacing. I had stripped that out since it wasn't "minimal" to reproducing the gap, and didn't realize that it affected the line spacing.)

Comment: Also, when setting fixed text body height (``\setuplayout [lines=42]``) the gap will move to the 42nd line. There’s got to be some counter that isn’t updated when the line height changes.

Comment: @phg, where is the best place to report that? http://tracker.luatex.org (which http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page describes as a bug tracker for ConTeXt and LuaTeX)? Somewhere on https://gitorious.org/context ?

Comment: @LarsH the Context mailing list, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131707/14066 -- just ping the list again using an absolute minimal example (without the grid setting etc). Since MkII is obsolete and Xetex was never really supported anyways, it is advisable to mention that this bug persists in MkIV.

Comment: @phg: Thanks. So mkii is obsolete? I've been unclear on that point. My impression was that mkiv was still beta and mkii was still supported. Can you point me to a published statement about the status of mkii?

Comment: @LarsH For a written statement you will have to ask Hans himself. Bugs in MkII are still fixed but development has stalled: features are neither added nor being backported from MkIV.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem either, I redered with mkiv and everything looks normal here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is no longer reproducible (neither with the latest beta `2019.01.07 16:10` nor with TeX Live 2018 `2018.04.04 00:51`).